# android spinner valus methods with another way

Tags: android

is there another way to do this ,i mean another method or sprate method ,to reduce coding,what i want is to  do the same thing but in diffreent way

```
 public static final int spinner1_op_val = 50;
public static final int spinner2_op_val = 10;
public static final int spinner3_op_val = 50;

  Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayList<Integer> spinner1_options = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i <= spinner1_op_val; i += 1) {
        spinner1_options.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter_for_spinner1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinner1_options);
    dataAdapter_for_spinner1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter_for_spinner1);
    spinner1.setSelection(4);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);





    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayList<Integer> spinner2_options = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i <= spinner2_op_val; i++) {
        spinner2_options.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter_for_spinner2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spinner2_options);
    dataAdapter_for_spinner2.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setSelection(2);
    spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter_for_spinner2);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);



    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayList<Integer> spinner3_option = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i <= spinner3_op_val; i += 5) {
        spinner3_option.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter_for_spinner3 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinner3_option);
    dataAdapter_for_spinner3.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner3.setAdapter(dataAdapter_for_spinner3);
    spinner3.setSelection(2);
    spinner3.setOnItemSe

     lectedListener(this);
```

extraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextraextra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes you can minimize your code just create a function like this.

```
public void setSpinnerItem(Spinner spinner, int value, int jump, int selection) {
    ArrayList<Integer> spinnerOption = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < value; i+=jump) {
        spinnerOption.add(Integer.valueOf(i));
    }
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> integerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, spinnerOption);
    integerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(integerArrayAdapter);
    spinner.setSelection(selection);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

> then to use the function.

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

setSpinnerItem(spinner1, spinner_op_val, forLoopJump, spinnerSelection);
setSpinnerItem(spinner2, spinner_op_val, forLoopJump, spinnerSelection);
setSpinnerItem(spinner3, spinner_op_val, forLoopJump, spinnerSelection);
```